# ubuntu apache restart error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ubuntu

I am getting below error...
What to do?

```
* Restarting web server apache2                                                /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Comment: Take a look at this hope it will help you..**http://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name**

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem You need set ServerName.

vim /etc/apache2/conf.d/name

For example set add ServerName localhost or any other name:

ServerName localhost

Restart Apache 2

service apache restart